# How to run the function when the events doesn't exists in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 multilingual app and I am fetching the data using the API according to the language selected and I have added event for that but the problem is that when the event value doesnt exist I want to run the default function.

This is my **chakapi.service.ts**:

```
getchallenges($id, $lang) {
   return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'getChallenges/' + $id + '/' + $lang);
}
```

In this service I am fetching the details on the basic of the id and selected language.

This is my **tab2.page.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChakapiService } from './../service/chakapi.service';
import { LoadingController, Events } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})
export class Tab2Page implements OnInit {
  challenges: any;
  challengesdetails: any;
  constructor(public chakapi: ChakapiService, public loadingController: LoadingController,
    private storage: Storage, public events: Events) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUserChallenges();
  }
  async getUserChallenges() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Please Wait',
      duration: 2200,
      translucent: true,
    });
    await loading.present();
    this.storage.get('ID').then((val2) => {
      if (val2) {
        this.events.subscribe('language:select', (datalang) => { // update from login
          if (datalang) {
            this.chakapi.getchallenges(val2, datalang).subscribe(data => {
              this.challenges = data;
              this.challengesdetails = this.challenges.data;
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
    return await loading.onDidDismiss();
  }
}
```

In this ts file, I am running the API and getting the details from the API on the basic of id and selected language.

This is my **app.component.ts**:

```
languageSelected: any = 'en';
selectLanguage(selectlang) {
this.events.publish('language:select', selectlang);
}
setLanguage() {
    const defaultLanguage = this.translate.getDefaultLang();
    if (this.languageSelected) {
      console.log(this.languageSelected);
      this.translate.setDefaultLang(this.languageSelected);
      this.translate.use(this.languageSelected);
      this.selectLanguage(this.languageSelected);
    } else {
      this.languageSelected = defaultLanguage;
      this.translate.use(defaultLanguage);
      this.selectLanguage(this.languageSelected);
    }
  }
```

My default selected language is 'en'.

In this ts file, I am selecting the language. I am sending the selected language using the events and it is working fine but when the app loads it doesn't show any data because the event has not exists.

I want to run the function in the `tab2.page.ts` when the event doesn't exists with the default language.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure but I think putting function "selectLanguage" of app.component.ts in the constructor or ngOnInit will publish your event automatically when that file loads. So, please check first whether that function is in constructor or ngOnInit or not.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd I have called that function in my constructor.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd. By default the "selectLanguage" function is not running.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd. It wont run by default because the event only run on the click.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd. Can you please provide the solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this. When you run the event save the value in the storage and when the event doesn't run then send the value from the storage. This will solve your problem.

In your **ts** file:

```
this.storage.get('LANG').then((vallang) => {
  if (vallang) {
    this.detailsfetch(vallang);
  }
});

this.events.subscribe('language:select', (data) => { // update from app.component.ts
  if (data) {
    this.detailsfetch(data);
  }
});
```